# Get data from dropdownlist and insert the value in dataBase

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to get a value from a drop-down list in order to insert in a table in my dataBase. I am using ajax in order to capture this value and draw a button that will insert the value in my database when the user clicks on it.

This is my code :

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('register_script_name', "
$('#editButton').click(function(){
   alert('edit');
   return false;
});
", CClientScript::POS_READY);

<div class="row">

<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Escolha a opção correta <span class="required">*</span>')?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'Opcoes_idOpcoes',$this->getOpcoesResposta(),
 array( 
 'ajax' => array(
                'type' => 'POST',
                'url'=>$this->createUrl('perguntaOpcoes/State'),   
                'data'=>array('Opcoes_idOpcoes'=>'js: $(this).val()'),
                'update' => '#data', 
               )      
 ));
?> 
</div>

<div id="data">



</div>
```

And this is my code in controller:

```
   public function actionState()
    {
        $data= $_POST['Opcoes_idOpcoes'];         

        echo  CHtml::button("Edit",array('title'=>"Edit",'id'=>"editButton",'onclick'=>'edit()'));      
    }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: and what is the problem exactly? I see some improvements and some things that may not work, but whats you exact issue?

Comment: nothing worked but i figured out the problem, thank you your time :)